# How can I call a Dart library created with DDC from JavaScript?

Tags: dart, dart-dev-compiler

I've created a large library in Dart that need to be called from JavaScript.  I'd like to avoid using JS Interop if possible.  Can I use the Dart Dev Compiler to do this?

Is it possible to take the JavaScript code generated by DDC and easily call it directly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'll need some @JS because otherwise, the tree-shaking will likely remove any need for the very entrypoints you want, and the code won't even be there.